# Chrome shows illegal invocation when running react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to change classes of my component's `div` tag. But I get illegal invocation. Here's my code.

I don't know what I am doing wrong? I am new to react and javascript. I am trying to float my `div` with `id` of `power` to left or right conditionally like a toggle switch. I get the error when I click on the `div`. Not in the beginning.

```js
let power = false;
let bank;
let target = document.getElementById;
function powerButton() {
  power = !power;
  if (power) {
    target("power").className = "float-right";
  } else {
    target("power").className = "float-left";
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-constructor
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <
          <div
            id="controls"
            className=" d-inline-block float-right  mt-5 text-center font-weight-bold  "
            style={{ marginRight: "40px" }}
          >
            <p style={{ margin: "0" }}>Power</p>
            <div
              onClick={powerButton}
              className=" mx-auto"
              style={{
                width: "54px",
                height: "24px",
                padding: "2px",
                backgroundColor: "black",
              }}
            >
              <div
                id="power"
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: "blue",
                  width: "23px",
                  height: "19px",
                  border: "1px solid black",
                }}
              />
            </div>
            <p
              style={{
                padding: "15px 0px",
                width: "200px",
                height: "45px",
                lineHeight: "22px",
                margin: "15px 0px ",
                backgroundColor: "grey",
              }}
            >
              AAA
            </p>
            <div style={{ marginBottom: "5px" }}>
              <input style={{ color: "black" }} type="range" />
            </div>
            <p style={{ margin: "0" }}>Bank</p>
            <div
              className=" mx-auto"
              style={{
                width: "54px",
                height: "24px",
                padding: "2px",
                backgroundColor: "black",
              }}
            >
              <div
                id="bank"
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: "blue",
                  width: "23px",
                  height: "19px",
                  border: "1px solid black",
                }}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have that error because you've lost the "context" of the function, I mean "document". To resolve this, use .bind in newer versions of Javascript:

```
if (power) {
  target.bind(document)("power").className = "float-right";
} else {
  target.bind(document)("power").className = "float-left";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The illegal invocation is because of wrong context i.e. getElementById is not being called by the document object. Also in React, do things via state updates and not direct DOM manipulation. You first need to understand core JavaScript concepts and learn React concepts from documentation.